# Android - Persist data retrieved from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistent-data

I have an activity and a model called `CourseDetails`.

```
String getData;
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("courses").child("Business");
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        CourseDetails c = dataSnapshot.getValue(CourseDetails.class);
        getData = c.getCourseName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

textview1.setText(getData);
```

Using above code throws `NullPointerException` at last line above. But if I put `textview1.setText(getData)` into the `ValueEventListener`, under `getData = c.getCourseName()`, the data can be displayed correctly.

Methods I found working are using `SharedPreferences` or setting data from a method such as `public void display(String data) { textview1.setText(data); }`. But what are the other ways to keep the retrieved data even if the data is outside `ValueEventListener`?

For instance I want to persist the data added into an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String> listData;
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("courses").child("Business");
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        CourseDetails c = dataSnapshot.getValue(CourseDetails.class);
        String code = c.getCourseCode();
        String name = c.getCourseName();
        String CodeName = code + " " + name;

        listData.add(CodeName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

// data in ArrayList should be able to display here
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : listData) {
   builder.append(s + "\n");
}

textview1.setText(builder.toString());
```

How to achieve this kind of persistence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, Firebase will notify all it's data listener attached to specific references (database references wherever the `addValueEventListener` is added) when those specific data gets modified. That is when 
`onDataChange` will be called, when there is modification of the data at those database references, 
(besides modification the method will always be called first time).

And this happens 
asynchronously, so in the first case where null occurs because we don't know whether data is retreived from Firebase and 
as far as I know, Android's main thread cannot be put on hold or pause until we retreive the data that's why we use Asynchronous tasks in Android.
So, I think the best way to do specific updates or task on data change is within `onDataChange` method. So, like you stated it could be 
done by making those changes within `onDataChange` itself or by calling some other method from onDataChange.

Or, if you are using 
adapter then, notifying adapter about the change within `onDataChange`. Also, you can take a look at other choice i.e. `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` then, 
it will handle the update automatically without any extra effort.

Comment: Hi again openSource. Thanks. If so, if I want to retrieve and save data from one node to `ArrayList A`, and retrieve data from another node and save to `ArrayList B`, can you suggest how to keep the data in both `ArrayLists` after the `EventListener` is removed?

Comment: The data in both `ArrayLists` will be used for comparison later on

Comment: Hello, I am not understanding quite well, does after `EventListener` is removed refers that you do not want the `ArrayLists` to be updated everytime the data is modified?

Comment: Yeah. It is actually `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in my code to retrieve data from Firebase. I corrected above code

Comment: My goal is to compare the data retrieved from the Firebase by using `ArrayLists`. Like first retrieve data from node A and add into `ArrayList A`, the `ValueEventListener` is then removed; then retrieve data from node B and add into `ArrayList B`, then remove `ValueEventListener`. Lastly only compare the data in both `ArrayList A` and `B`

Comment: So, `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will resolve your issue right? Are you looking at other alternatives of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent `? You could try calling `mRef.removeEventListener(this);` at the end onf `onDataChange` to remove listener once, you receive the values you needed.

Comment: Everything is working. But is it possible to keep and compare the data in `ArrayLists` after the `EventListener` is removed? The second part of code in my question, the one with `ArrayList`, data is added into the `ArrayList`, but running the code throws `NullPointerException`. It seems like the data is removed from `ArrayList` as soon as the `EventListener` is removed

Comment: Do you mind to go to this [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era)?

Comment: I haven't used one before, can you create one and send me invitation?