# Android - Retrieve data from different nodes in Firebase

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two nodes in Firebase, `business` and `science`, both under a same parent called `courses`

```
{
  "courses" : {
    "business" : {
      "-KP-EadFq_rsXymxbUas" : {
        "courseCHours" : "4",
        "courseCode" : "BIZ2000",
        "courseName" : "Business Mathematics",
        "courseYear" : "1",
        "prerequisite" : {
          "-KP-EcGRXCtlXYQvjoYo" : {
            "preMainCourse" : "Business Mathematics",
            "preSubCourse" : "null"
          }
        },
        "sections" : {
          "-KP-EbIkS1jxVfNIE5jH" : {
            "sectionCode" : "A1",
            "sectionSeats" : "20"
          },
          "-KP-EbklnKpsUIIz_U68" : {
            "sectionCode" : "A2",
            "sectionSeats" : "20"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "science" : {
      "-KP-EKJeu5PdfyJZnIVk" : {
        "courseCHours" : "4",
        "courseCode" : "SCI3000",
        "courseName" : "Science Fundamentals",
        "courseYear" : "1",
        "prerequisite" : {
          "-KP-EOVlKZx4zofkg5RT" : {
            "preMainCourse" : "Science Fundamentals",
            "preSubCourse" : "null"
          }
        },
        "sections" : {
          "-KP-EM8vYB9d0-axX8Cr" : {
            "sectionCode" : "A1",
            "sectionSeats" : "20"
          },
          "-KP-EModVxv_Vc3SBZ_G" : {
            "sectionCode" : "A2",
            "sectionSeats" : "20"
          }
        }
      },
      "-KP-EVvdvHgqxGPsxCrE" : {
        "courseCHours" : "4",
        "courseCode" : "SCI3100",
        "courseName" : "Science History",
        "courseYear" : "1",
        "prerequisite" : {
          "-KP-EXa8naK5uF7y9py2" : {
            "preMainCourse" : "Science History",
            "preSubCourse" : "null"
          }
        },
        "sections" : {
          "-KP-EWX0hh8q5d5YTkVR" : {
            "sectionCode" : "A1",
            "sectionSeats" : "20"
          },
          "-KP-EWu8pWXS1aR9zh_4" : {
            "sectionCode" : "A2",
            "sectionSeats" : "20"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`CourseDetails` model

```
public class CourseDetails {

    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private String courseCHours;
    private String courseYear;
    private String courseKey;

    public CourseDetails() {
    }

    public CourseDetails(String courseCode, String courseName, String courseCHours, String courseYear) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseCHours = courseCHours;
        this.courseYear = courseYear;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getCourseKey() {
        return courseKey;
    }

    public void setCourseKey(String courseKey) {
        this.courseKey = courseKey;
    }

    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseCHours() {
        return courseCHours;
    }

    public void setCourseCHours(String courseCHours) {
        this.courseCHours = courseCHours;
    }

    public String getCourseYear() {
        return courseYear;
    }

    public void setCourseYear(String courseYear) {
        this.courseYear = courseYear;
    }
}
```

Code I'm trying to get data from both nodes

```
ArrayList<String> businessList;
ArrayList<String> scienceList;

DatabaseReference businessRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("courses").child("business");

businessRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        displayBusiness(dataSnapshot);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

DatabaseReference scienceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("courses").child("science");

scienceRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        displayScience(dataSnapshot);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

public void displayBusiness(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        CourseDetails c = ds.getValue(CourseDetails.class);
        String code = c.getCourseCode();
        String name = c.getCourseName();
        String CodeName = code + " " + name;

        businessList.add(CodeName);
    }
}

public void displayScience(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        CourseDetails c = ds.getValue(CourseDetails.class);
        String code = c.getCourseCode();
        String name = c.getCourseName();
        String CodeName = code + " " + name;

        scienceList.add(CodeName);
    }
}
```

Using the code above seems like returns the `ArrayLists` with empty data.

My goal is to retrieve the data and store in different `ArrayList`, `businessList` and `scienceList`. Both the `ArrayLists` will be used for comparing the data.

My problem is the retrieved data does not persist in the `ArrayLists`. How to make sure that the retrieved data is stored in the `ArrayLists` so that I can compare the data later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not attaching the listener to the right reference.

Change it to these

```
businessRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
scienceRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

**EDIT**

Inside the iteration, you're not calling the getValue from the entry.
Change to this

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    CourseDetails c = ds.getValue(CourseDetails.class);
```

You want to make sure that the comparison method is called only when both of the listeners have called onDataChange,  You can [use my solution in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685879/continue-execution-after-data-received-from-multiple-location-in-firebase/38686596#38686596) or [use a utility class from an answer from a firebaser here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173569/only-load-layout-when-firebase-calls-are-complete/38188683#38188683).

Comment: Hi again Wilik. Really sorry I forgot to update that part. Both the `Listeners` are actually correctly referenced. I updated my code

Comment: ah okay, can you post your database structure and `CourseDetails` class? @LorekBryanson

Comment: Ok. Edited my question with the structure

Comment: For the `sections` and `prerequisite` nodes, I use another two different models

Comment: I'm really sorry for all the stupid mistakes. In my actual code, the `getValue()` is called correctly also. I edited my code. I'm now checking for other silly mistakes. Really sorry. Can you please check again?

Comment: I already tested the code. Everything can be printed out correctly if the printing is done inside `onDataChange`

Comment: It's exactly like my another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926158/android-persist-data-retrieved-from-firebase). If I wanted to compare the `ArrayLists` outside `onDataChange`, the data inside the `ArrayLists` are null

Comment: @LorekBryanson I see. Because these listeners work asynchronously, you can't do the comparison before both of them is finished (before `onDataChange` is called). You can use [my solution in another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685879/continue-execution-after-data-received-from-multiple-location-in-firebase/38686596#38686596) or use a utility class from [an answer from a firebaser here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173569/only-load-layout-when-firebase-calls-are-complete/38188683#38188683). Hope those helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Will try your solution and get back to you

Comment: Do you mind to go to this [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era)?

Comment: @LorekBryanson it's better to create a new one, because it's hard to track a topic when there's a lot of people talking about multiple topics

Comment: Hi Wilik. Thanks for replying. Can you go to this [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)?